# Array into TextView

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I have some two-dimensional array.

```
int a[i][j]
```

I want to display it.
I'm trying:

```
            String aa = ""; 
            aa+=(a[i][j] + "\n");
            table.append(aa);
```

But it not working - there are just one "0".
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it complete code? Do you have any loops? What is `table`?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov `TextView table;` No loops there.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov array filled by "0" and "1".

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to make a table:

```
int a[][] = new int[][]{{0,1,2,3,4},
                        {2,3,4,5,6},
                        {2,3,4,5,6}};

StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
        strBuild.append(a[i][j]);
        strBuild.append(" ");
    }
    strBuild.append("\n");
}

yourTextVeiw.setText(strBuild.toString());
```

If you are trying to put all the numbers in one row:

```
int a[][] = new int[][]{{0,1,2,3,4},
                        {2,3,4,5,6},
                        {2,3,4,5,6}};

StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
        strBuild.append(a[i][j]);
        strBuild.append(" ");
    }
}

yourTextView.setText(strBuild.toString());
```

If you are trying to make them all in one column:

```
int a[][] = new int[][]{{0,1,2,3,4},
                        {2,3,4,5,6},
                        {2,3,4,5,6}};

StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
        strBuild.append(a[i][j]);
        strBuild.append("\n");
    }
}
yourTextView.setText(strBuild.toString());
```

and one row all smashed together:

```
int a[][] = new int[][]{{0,1,2,3,4},
                        {2,3,4,5,6},
                        {2,3,4,5,6}};

StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
        strBuild.append(a[i][j]);
    }
}
yourTextView.setText(strBuild.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int[][] array = new int[][]{
        {1, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1}
};

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int[] arr : array)
    builder.append(Arrays.toString(arr)).append("\n");

String tableText = builder.toString();
```

`tableText` is string:

```
"[1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]"
```

So assuming you have `TextView` named `table`, all you have to do, is set this string as your `TextView`'s text:

```
table.setText(tableText);
```

Comment: i've got my array in the Text View, but there are hundreds of numbers
May be i should declare array in a different way?
`int[][] a = new int [100][100];`

Comment: i can't code
 `int[][] array = new int[][]{
        {1, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1}
};`, cause this is truth table and i create it in the code.

Comment: @AlexanderVasilchuk You can create array whatever way you want. It's just an example.

Comment: @SergeyGlotov i understood, my table displays all array now, filling not used cells by "0". How can i display only cells, which i use?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov i've got 16*16, but use 8*8:
[Screen](https://pp.vk.me/c630831/v630831324/31d55/jguv82z-UsU.jpg)

Comment: @SergeyGlotov and i can't point exact size of array on declaring, cause in previously activity it points dynamically

Comment: "i've got 16*16, but use 8*8". Don't write empty rows. About zeros in a row – you need something more. `Arrays.toString()` can't write a part of array. You need to pass to the method a subarray or use one of another answers.

Comment: @AlexanderVasilchuk "and i can't point exact size of array on declaring" Why do you need to point exact size? You already have array from previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[][] = new int[][] {
   { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 7, 9 },
   { 4, 5, 6, 4, 8, 6, 1, 3, 6, 7 },
   { 7, 1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 3, 5, 8 },
   { 8, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 4, 9 },
   { 9, 8, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7 }
  };
String aa = ""; 

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
         for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
         {
         aa.concat(String.valueOf(a[i][j]));
         }
    }

    (your text view) .setText(aa);
```

Comment: The length of the elements of a two-dimensional array in Java need not be equal. Hardcoding of the upper bound of j-loop can be wrong potentially.

Answer (score 1):

You need loop, obviously :) You are getting only one element of array now from a[i][j].

Something like

```
String aa;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        aa += a[i][j];
    }
}
table.setText(aa);
```

And add somewhere line feed ("\n") if you need it

Comment: @TeWu's version is better in fact :) I just wanted to show basics.